Local approximation of geodesic distance
Consider a surface $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ which is the graph of a function $Z(x,y)$ and two points $p,q\in S$ which are "very close to each other". Is there a simple (and computationally fast) approximation of the geodesic distance $d(p,q)$? Basically, if $p=(x_0,y_0,Z(x_0,y_0))$ is fixed, I am interested in computing the first terms of the Taylor expansion of
$$(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mapsto d\big(p,(x,y,Z(x,y)\big)^2$$
centered at $(x_0,y_0)$.
Similarly, consider a small triangle $\tau\subset S$ whose vertices are $p,q,r\in S$ and whose edges are geodesics. Is there a reasonable and computationally fast approximation of the area of $\tau$?
Thoughts. I have only taken two courses on the geometry of curves and surfaces, so I am no expert. I feel like you should be able to do something with the first and second variationa formulas, but I can't put a finger on it. I have checked this related question, If I understood it correctly, it implies that the first derivatives of $d\big(p,(x,y,Z(x,y)\big)^2$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ are $0$, which is to be expected, but also not very helpful.
Motivation.
I am working on the generation of triangle meshes on surfaces. To evaluate the quality of the grid, for each triangle $\tau$, I compute the following quality measure
$$
q(\tau)=4\sqrt{3}\frac{A}{l_{1}^{2}+l_{2}^{2}+l_{3}^{2}},
$$
where $A$ is the area of $\tau$ and $l_i$ are the edge lengths. The idea is that $q(\tau)$ is small for skinny triangles and close to $1$ for equilateral triangles. I can do this if I take $\tau$ to be flat, but I would like to compute $q(\tau)$ for a curved triangle as well.
